# Splash screen to show up in the middle of application

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a list of report names displayed as Tree hierarchy in ReportViewer control. When user clicks on a report name, an input form loads, user enters some values and presses OK. At this point, Splash screen should load while the backend process is happening (connecting to DB, retrieving values etc). Once the report is loaded in Reportviewer editor, the splashscreen should close.

So far, I am able to display the splash screen however it gets stuck at that point, the actual report does not load and the splash screen stays on forever.

Is it possible to use splashscreen in the middle of application, not at app launch? If so, how do I continue with loading report?

```
static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)

    {

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new SnapPlusReports());

        //new SplashScreenApp().Run(args);
    }
}

public class SplashScreenApp : WindowsFormsApplicationBase
{
    private static SplashScreenApp _application;

    public static void Run(Form form)
    {
        _application = new SplashScreenApp { MainForm = form };
        _application.Run(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs());
    }

    protected override void OnCreateSplashScreen()
    {
        this.SplashScreen = new ShowProgress();
        base.OnCreateSplashScreen();
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `BeginInvoke()` to run it on a separate thread?  Also, you didn't have it display as Modal, right?  Please post some code for a specific solution...

Comment: Are you sure you have got your work scheduled on a background thread on not the UI thread itself?

Comment: @allen - I am trying to do it with Visual Basic assembly. Here's a link -  http://www.softwarepassion.com/windows-forms-application-with-splash-screen/

Comment: @PinnyM - Added some code. It works ok on app launch. But thats not what I want. I want the progress bar to load and then it should close when the reportviewer editor loads with the report.

Comment: I am curious if you even found a solution to this problem and what you used.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this before by making a new form at run time dynamically with code. Make sure you set all the options up, especially FormBorderStyle to none, or something like that so the user can't close it. Then simply manipulate labels that appear on that form, and eventually close it once your process is complete.
This way you don't have to worry about threading and a nice side effect is that the initial form won't be clickable.

For example I have an about form that pops up during run time (granted I don't change anything on it but the idea is there:

```
AboutForm aboutForm = new AboutForm();
aboutForm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
Label lblAbout = new Label();
Version applicationVersion = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version;
lblAbout.Text = applicationVersion.ToString();
lblAbout.Location = new Point(145,104);
aboutForm.Controls.Add(lblAbout);
aboutForm.ShowDialog();
```

This shows the current programs version number, etc. There are other labels that already exist on the form (I created it visually first and then called an instance of it).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Does this have the progress bar? or just forms with labels?

Comment: You can add a progress bar in the same way that the label is added. i.e. ProgressBar pgBar = new ProgressBar(); . Then you can edit its location, properties, etc. in the same way as the label.

Answer (score 0):

...Catch other instances and gracefully exit if you need only one copy of your app in memory at a given time

```
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    bool exclusive;
    System.Threading.Mutex appMutex = new System.Threading.Mutex(true, "MY_APP", out exclusive);
    if (!exclusive)
    {
         MessageBox.Show("Another instance of xxxx xxxBuilder is already running.","MY_APP",
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                        MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation );
                    return;
    }
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    xxxWindowsApplication.InitializeApplication();
    Application.Run(new frmMenuBuilderMain());
                GC.KeepAlive(appMutex);
            }
```

In the main form load you could do something like:

```
private void frmMenuBuilderMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   

     //Show Splash with timeout Here--
     if(!SystemLogin.PerformLogin())             
     {
         this.Close();
         return;
     }
     tmrLoad.Enabled = true;
```

}